# Override SetRowLabelValue to what

Tags: wxpython

The documentation states that if you are creating a grid, and you want to set the row labels, you must override SetRowLabelValue. Great, no problem, just what is the variable name you store the label into?

```
def SetRowLabelValue(self, row, label):
    # store where?
    return label
```

I tried rowLabels (to match the col labels) but that doesn't work. What's the variable name? I'm sure I'm just missing it somewhere but I also tried looking in memory and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple thing, SetRowLabelValue is to let you assign a variable to store into. Then you override GetRowLabelValue to return your info. This has to occur in the derivative of GridTableBase. So the sequence is:

```
def SetRowLabelValue(self, row, label):
    self.rowLabels[row] = label
    return label

def GetRowLabelValue(self, row)
    return self.rowLabels[row]
```

And you can pick any variable name that you like. The documentation is a bit obscure but this does the trick.